# Minimizing deadlocks with purposely contrived + highly concurrent transactions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently working on benchmarking different isolation levels in SQL Server 2008 -- but right now I'm stuck on what seems to be a trivial deadlocking problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Hopefully someone here can offer advice (I'm a novice to SQL)

I currently have two types of transactions (to demonstrate dirty reads, but that's irrelevant):

Transaction Type A:  Select all rows from Table A.

Transaction Type B:  Set value 'cost' = 0 in all rows in Table A, then rollback immediately.

I currently run a threadpool of 1000 threads and 10,000 transactions, where each thread randomly chooses between executing Transaction Type A and Transaction Type B.  However, I'm getting a ton of deadlocks even with forced row locking.

I assume that the deadlocks are occurring because of the row ordering of locks being acquired -- that is, if both Type A and Type B 'scan' table A in the same ordering, e.g. from top to bottom, such deadlocks cannot occur.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get SQL Server to maintain row ordering during SELECT and UPDATE statements.

Any tips?  First time poster to stackoverflow, so please be gentle :-)

EDIT:  The isolation level is purposely set to READ_COMMITTED to show that it eliminates dirty reads (and it does).  Deadlocks only occur on any level equal to or higher than READ_COMMITTED;  obviously no deadlocks occur on READ_UNCOMMITTED.

EDIT 2:  These transactions are being run on a fresh instance of AdventureWorks LT on SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: To clarify, my understanding is this:

A deadlock can occur if XACT A selects rows in an increasing fashion, and XACT B updates rows in a decreasing fashion, e.g.:  XACT A acquires lock on row 1;  XACT A acquires lock on row 2, relinquishes lock on row 1;  XACT B acquires lock on row 3, wants to access row 2, but is blocked; XACT A wants to access row 3, but is blocked.


However, if XACT A and XACT B goes through rows in the same order, obviously such deadlocks cannot occur.  How do I enforce this?

Comment: Can you provide table structure (including indexes) and the deadlock graph from SQL Profiler?

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting a transaction to update all the rows, type B, and then rollback the transaction, the lock will need to be held for that entire transaction on all rows. Even though you have row level locks the lock needs to be held for the entire transaction.

You may see less deadlocks if you have page level or table level locking because these are easier to handle for Sql Server, but you will still need to hold these locks on the whole whilst the transaction is ongoing.

When you are designing a highly concurrent system you should avoid queries that lock the whole table. I recommend the following MicroSoft guide for understanding locks and reducing their impact:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx

Comment: I simplified my 'application' to execute the same single query: Update table A where rowID = '123'.  However, there are deadlocking issues whenever I run 300+ such queries concurrently with the isolation level set to READ_COMMITTED or higher.  Furthermore, the errors still occur with row locking/table locking hints!  Interestingly enough, I still get these SQL exceptions even on Snapshot Isolation, which, as far as I know, does not use locks.

Comment: Actually, I have a feeling that it may be due to some other resource (not locks) that are causing the deadlocks.  The deadlock graph via SQL Profiler shows the victim process (crossed out), connected to a "Thread Pool", which is then connected to hundreds of other processes.  No mention of any lock.  You can see the graph here:

[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4489384/deadlock_graph.jpg)